# How to include dompdf without composer

Tags: php, dompdf

I want to use dompdf in my php website and I try to include the library without Composer and I can not get it to work.

The code I try to test is:

```
<?php
include "../../plugins/dompdf/Autoloader.php";
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();
?>
```

But i get the error:

`Fatal error: Class 'Dompdf' not found ...`

Can anyone explain me how to include the library without install composer in the server?

Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

With the right include is working like a charm, as said Samrap i was including the wrong file.

Now the code is:

```
 <?php
 //Configure the directory where you have the dompdf
 require_once "../../plugins/dompdf/autoload.inc.php";
 use Dompdf\Dompdf;
 //$dompdf = new dompdf();
 //$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
 $dompdf = new Dompdf();
 $dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');
 // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
 $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
 // Render the HTML as PDF
 $dompdf->render();
 // Output the generated PDF to Browser
 $dompdf->stream();
 ?>
```

Thank you Samrap for your help.

Comment: how to include this libraries in magento 2?

Comment: I don't have that file, 'autoload.inc.php', where to find it??

Answer (score 4):

You're requiring the wrong autoload file. The docs clearly state to include this file for autoloading:

`require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';`

If you look at that file, you'll see it does require `Autoloader.php` but performs a few other bootstrapping tasks as well.

Comment: Thank you Samrap, you are right. I fixed the include and give me an error for the libraries php-font-lib and php-svg-lib. I installed the libraries and the error comes again: Fatal error: Class 'Dompdf' not found.

Comment: I forget to put "use Dompdf\Dompdf;" that solve the issue and now is working. Thank you Samrap.